# How to change video source on click of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, src

First, sorry, I'm French, so I don't speak/write english very well...

Basically, I want to change a video source on click on a button.
For now, to have something simple, it's the same button that plays the video.

To do it, I looked on answers displayed on this website and tried to apply it. But it doesn't work and I'm not able at all to know why...

Could you help me please ?

Here is the body :

```
    <video id="myVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    preload="auto" width="960" height="396"
    poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png">

        <source id='mp4Source' src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source id='oggSource' src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>

    </video>

    <!-- Bouton Commencer -->
    <input type="button" value="Commencer" id="StartButton">
    <p> Commencer </p>
    </input>
```

And here is the script :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        videojs("myVideo").ready(function(){
            var myPlayer = this;

            var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');
            var oggVid = document.getElementById('oggSource');

            $('#StartButton').click(function(){

                myPlayer.pause();

                $(mp4Vid).attr('src', "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");
                $(oggVid).attr('src', "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv");

                myPlayer.load();
                myPlayer.play();
            });
        });         
    });
```

I want it to play the "small.mp4" video, but it plays the "ocean-clips.mp4" video...

Thank you very much !

Comment: Try rebuilding the whole video tag. First, you stop it, then you get it's `outerHTML` and you destroy it and rebuild everything. It's a bit of a bad idea, but might work.

Comment: Works for me on Chrome: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwa0nzxm/)

Comment: Indeed, and that's very weird, cause I try it on Chrome too. Maybe I have something wrong with the rest of the html code.
My version can be seen here : http://www.thomaspollet.fr/O2/test_video_V3.html
Could you please tell me if it works for you ? TY

Comment: On FF 32.0 it works too

Comment: Thank for your answers ! Are you talking about the code I posted or the link I gave in my previous comment ?

Comment: Ok it works indeed on FF, sorry i didn't try that first... But still not working on Chrome. Can it be a cache issue ? How can I resolve it ?

Comment: The code on your site works for me when I add this line: `$('#myVideo_html5_api').attr('src', "http://.../small.mp4");`

Comment: Thanks a lot, blex, it works ! I can't really understand why, but the most important is that it perfectly works, thanks again !

Comment: Do you know how I can say that the topic is resolved and that your answer is working ? TY

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:

```
$(function(){
    $('#StartButton').click(function(){
        $('#mp4Source').attr('src', "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");
        $('#oggSource').attr('src', "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv");
        $('#myVideo').load();
        $('#myVideo').attr('autoplay','autoplay');
    });
});
```

or, if you want first play first video and then change, use this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myVideo').attr('autoplay','autoplay');
    $('#StartButton').click(function(){
        $('#mp4Source').attr('src', "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");
        $('#oggSource').attr('src', "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv");
        $('#myVideo').load();
        $('#myVideo').play();
    });
});
```

---

By the way, input is not a pair tag. The correct enrollment is

```
<input type="button" value="Commencer" id="StartButton" />
```

or

```
<button id="StartButton">
    Commencer
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually the solution gave by blex is working, so I will use it.